# How do I convert this code so the functions can take a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of nav bar elements when the mouse goes over them.

This piece of code does that but for only the first button:

```
let navOne = document.getElementById("nav1");

function mouseOn() {
    nav1.style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOff() {
    nav1.style.color = "black";
}

navOne.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOn);
navOne.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOff);
```

I have been trying to convert the code so the functions work for multiple buttons, but cannot seem to get it to work. Here is the code so far:

```
let navOne = document.getElementById("nav1");

function mouseOn(navButton) {
    navButton.style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOff(navButton) {
    navButton.style.color = "black";
}

navOne.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOn(navOne));
navOne.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOff(navOne));
```

It has no errors, but does not cause any color change when I move my mouse button over the nav1 element.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mouseOn(navOne)` calls the function immediately ... on another note `this` inside the functions is the element that triggered the event - so, no need to pass the example `navOne` as `this === navOne` inside `mouseOn`

Comment: of course, you could use CSS `:hover` for such a simple effect

Comment: alternatively `navOne.addEventListener('mouseover', () => mouseOn(navOne));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the event handler functions take advantage of the `event` parameter that is passed in:

```js
function mouseOn(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "red";
}

function mouseOff(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "black";
}

for (let navItem of document.querySelectorAll('nav a')) {
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOn);
  navItem.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOff);
}
```

```css
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="nav1">Nav One</a>
  <a href="#" id="nav2">Nav Two</a>
</nav>
```

However, using a css `:hover` pseudo-attribute would be the preferred approach nowadays. No JS code needed.

```css
nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Nav One</a>
  <a href="#">Nav Two</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: or use `this` :p

Comment: @Bravo Yes, I prefer not to use `this` when I don't have to, but that is an option.